# socket gets closed after connection refused - is this a normal behaviour?

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection

I am playing around with android socket interface , I understood from the documentation that 
.isConnected() and isClosed() methods does not say anything about the socket status but 
however these indication if we had called connect and close on the socket.

In my application i am implementing retry with 10 seconds delay between the attempts, 
I am seeing a strange thing if i get connection refused from the server my next attempts are 
failing because the socket is closed.

is that really the case ?

here is my connection function:

```
  private boolean ConnectToServer() {
        int retry = 0;
        try {
            ServerIP = InetAddress.getByName(mServer);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SocketAddress mSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ServerIP, mPort);

        while ((!mSocket.isConnected()) && retry < 10) {
            mLogger.setMessage("Status isConnected:"+mSocket.isConnected()+"Status isClosed:"+mSocket.isClosed());
            mLogger.sendLog();
            try {
                mSocket.connect(mSocketAddress, 3000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            retry++;
            mLogger.setMessage("Attempting to connect to server - Sleeping for 5 Seconds Rety="+retry);
            mLogger.sendLog();
            SystemClock.sleep(5000);
        }
        mLogger.setMessage("Returning from attempting connection with socket status "+mSocket.isConnected());
        return mSocket.isConnected();

    }
```

and here are corresponding logs

```
2020-03-05 09:51:37.200 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o D/poker5o: Buildup new Socket - still null isclosed=false
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.201 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o D/poker5o: Status isConnected:falseStatus isClosed:false
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.203 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 55555) from /10.0.2.15 (port 39702) after 3000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:288)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:193)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at com.eddieharari.poker5o.SignalChannel.ConnectToServer(SignalChannel.java:95)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at com.eddieharari.poker5o.SignalChannel.manageConnection(SignalChannel.java:109)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at com.eddieharari.poker5o.SignalChannel.run(SignalChannel.java:57)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.206 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:275)
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.207 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:   ... 11 more
    2020-03-05 09:51:37.207 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o D/poker5o: Attempting to connect to server - Sleeping for 5 Seconds Rety=1
    2020-03-05 09:51:42.208 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o D/poker5o: Status isConnected:falseStatus isClosed:false
    2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:139)
    2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at com.eddieharari.poker5o.SignalChannel.ConnectToServer(SignalChannel.java:95)
2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at com.eddieharari.poker5o.SignalChannel.manageConnection(SignalChannel.java:109)
2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at com.eddieharari.poker5o.SignalChannel.run(SignalChannel.java:57)
2020-03-05 09:51:42.209 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o D/poker5o: Attempting to connect to server - Sleeping for 5 Seconds Rety=2
2020-03-05 09:51:44.291 23239-23273/com.eddieharari.poker5o D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb61a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdb60f1d0)
2020-03-05 09:51:47.211 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o D/poker5o: Status isConnected:falseStatus isClosed:false
2020-03-05 09:51:47.212 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2020-03-05 09:51:47.212 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:139)
2020-03-05 09:51:47.212 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
2020-03-05 09:51:47.212 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
2020-03-05 09:51:47.212 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
2020-03-05 09:51:47.212 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2020-03-05 09:51:47.213 23239-23296/com.eddieharari.poker5o W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
```

As you can see from the log , when i call prior to connect to isClosed method it returns false , but just right after i try to connect and the exception i get is socket closed.

The only time i dont get socket closed is on the first attempt , that leads me to understand that the OS is closing the socket ... however how can i attempt rety in such case and also how do i know if OS had closed the socket on some other reason ?

Comment: Yes, it's normal behaviour. No, you can't reuse the socket.

Comment: Why are you printing the retry message even after you've succeeded?

Comment: Printing retry my bad , but does not really effect the flow....

Comment: Kayaman - Any advise as for how do i implement retry ?

Should i close thread and start new one from activity and handle it there ?
Or should i spawn new thread from current thread and close original thread ?

Answer (score 1):

> I am seeing a strange thing.  If I get connection refused from the server my next attempts are failing because the socket is closed.
>
> Is that really the case ?

Yes.  A failed connect will close the `Socket` and you won't be able to use it again.

> That leads me to understand that the OS is closing the socket.

Actually, in some cases the close is being initiated by Java.  (Not that it really matters.)

> How can I attempt retry in such case.

You need to discard the `Socket` object, create another one and connect with *that*.  The basic retry logic looks something like this:

```
SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(...);
while (retry <= NOS_RETRIES) {
    Socket = new Socket();
    try {
        socket.connect(address, port);
        return socket;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // possibly log exception
        if (/* it makes no sense to retry */) {
           // rethrow e, or return null
        }
    retry++;
    // delay
}
// rethrow last e, or return null
```

> How do I know if OS had closed the socket for some other reason?

You can catch and examine the exception that was thrown to determine why the `connect` call failed.

The precise exceptions that will be thrown depends on the context, and is not specified.  The `javadoc` lists `IOException`, `IllegalBlockingModeException`, or `IllegalArgumentException`, but in reality various types of `IOException` are also possible.  These include:

- `UnknownHostException` - if you use an `InetAddress` with a hostname, and the hostname is unknown.
- `BindException` - typically a local port is already in use
- `ConnectException` - connection refused or connection attempt timed out,
- `SocketTimeoutException` - connection attempt timed out,
- `NoRouteToHostException` - typically the remote host is off,
- `ProtocolException` - a transport level protocol error,
- `SocketException` - for various things like trying to connect a connected or closed socket.

Some of these won't be applicable to your use-case, and others may never be seen in practice.

Comment: the only thing i do not understand is why the .isclosed method returns false... but i guess it is what it is...

Comment: It is a bit difficult to explain why that might happen (complicated).  But you shouldn't need to use `isClosed` in the retry code anyway.